# Редактирование записи

Tags: jquery, javascript, вёрстка

Мне необходимо реализовать следующий функционал: при нажатии на определенный текст должно открываться всплывающее окно (или возникать форма на месте текста в том же окне), в котором можно было бы отредактировать текст. Как это реализовать с точки зрения javascript и jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("div.edit").live('click',function(){
                    var text = $(this).html();
                    var txtarea = $("<textarea id=\"textarea\">"+text+"</textarea>");
                    var parent = $(this).parent()
                    $(parent).html(txtarea);
                });
                $('#textarea').live('keydown',function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        var text = $(this).val();
                        var div = $("<div class=\"edit\">"+text+"</div>");
                        var parent = $(this).parent();
                        $(parent).html(div);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="editable">
            <div class="edit">Некоторый текст 1</div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="editable">
            <div class="edit">Некоторый текст 2</div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="editable">
            <div class="edit">Некоторый текст 3</div>
        </div>
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPD:** обновил для нескольких элементов

Comment: Да, это действительно работает) Но как быть, если на странице несколько элементов, которые нужно такие образом отредактировать? И еще нужно передать новое значение РНР скрипту?

Comment: тогда для селектора используйте классы, а в обработке нажатия ентера отправляйте данные скрипту через [jQuery.ajax()](api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: как я и предполагал, всё уже написано до нас: [Edit In Place Plugin For jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)